# Do Kähler realizations of symplectic manifolds exist?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds, poisson-geometry

> If $(S, \omega)$ is a smooth (not necessarily analytic!) symplectic manifold, does there exist a (almost-)Kähler manifold $K$ and a surjective Poisson submersion $\pi : K \to S$?

Think of $\Bbb R ^{2n}$ with coordinates $x_1, \dots, x_n, p_1, \dots, p_n$ and the usual symplectic form $\sum \textrm d x_i \wedge d p_i$. On $\Bbb C ^{2n}$ with complex coordinates $$x_1 + \textrm i y_1, \dots, x_n + \textrm i y_n, p_1 + \textrm i q_1, \dots, p_n + \textrm i q_n$$ consider the symplectic form $$\sum \textrm d x_i \wedge d p_i + \sum \textrm d y_i \wedge d q_i .$$ It is easy to check then that $$\pi (x_1 + \textrm i y_1, \dots, x_n + \textrm i y_n, p_1 + \textrm i q_1, \dots, p_n + \textrm i q_n) = (x_1, \dots, x_n, p_1, \dots, p_n)$$ is a Poisson map.

Of course, the above can be done for any finite-dimensional symplectic real vector space, by complexification.

Attempting to answer my own question, I wonder whether the $K$ that I am after could be constructed as some sort of "complexification" of $M$. Unfortunately, the only things about manifold complexifications that I know of are from two articles by Kulkarni from the '70s, one [extremely concise](http://www.pnas.org/content/72/11/4210.full.pdf), and the other one [not freely available](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01389901) (and not really answering my question).